# Return value by key

Tags: r, key

Is there a shorter way to return the values by key in the order, which is given by elements of key?

```
vars<-c("a"=1,"b"=2)
key<-c("b","a")
ret<-c()
for(k in key)
ret<-c(ret,vars[names(vars) %in% k])
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply want `vars[key]`.

Comment: No, because at first I want to check if names(vars) %in% key.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. If my answer doesn't help you, you need to explain more clearly, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe `vars[key[key %in% names(vars)]]` then? I'd say it's your fault Klaus for not giving us a representative example...

Comment: Or how about just `na.omit( vars[key] )` to take care of entries in `key` that don't appear in `vars`

Comment: @Klaus I have to agree with flodel. Your questions is not unambiguous or particularly clear, and sadly that is not an uncommon trait in your previous questions. You should spend more time making your questions clearer please.

Comment: @flodel Okay the example could be much clearer, all of you suggest the right answer `na.omit(vars[key])`,`vars[key[key %in% names(vars)]]` and `vars[ intersect(key,names(vars)) ]` gives the same result like in the start post, would you prefer one command?

Comment: e.g. the loop can used for both, if keys is given by list or as vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think `intersect` could be useful to you...

```
vars[ intersect(key,names(vars)) ]
#b a 
#2 1
```

Comment: @flodel I sometimes get my pants in a twist.

Comment: that works. let's mention it assumes `key` does not have duplicates which is the case with the OP's current example.